# dynamically update google trends embedded script from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I want to use an embedded google trends widget in a website.
Basically what I want, is to be able to select a word from a drop down menu, and to show the google trends chart of that word.

To be able to add the widget, I tried to use the script tag, but then I cannot update it dynamically, but only after a full refresh of the page.

Please advise.
thanks

I'm using this in my HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/1087_RC03/embed_loader.js">
                                </script>
                                <script type="text/javascript" id="reloadScript">
                                    STATE.init([]);
                                    trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword": STATE.active_symbol(),"geo":"","time":"today 1-m"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"date=today 1-m&q=STATE.active_symbol()","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"});
                                </script>
```

and this in my javascript file:

```
var STATE = STATE || (function(){
var activeSymbol = localStorage.getItem('activeSymbol');
    var _args = {}; // private
    return {
        init : function(Args) {
            _args = Args;
            // some other initialising
        },
        active_symbol : function() {
            return activeSymbol;
        }
    };
}());
```

Comment: I think that if you run the `trends.embed.renderExploreWidget` function again with the data of the new word, it should work

Comment: I would like to run it from the js file. do you know how can it be done?